# Installing an editor plugin in web2py app

Tags: ckeditor, web2py

I am trying to install an editor plugin "ck-editor4" in my web2py app, following the steps at:

http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1952/ck-editor4-plugin
and
https://bitbucket.org/PhreeStyle/web2py_ckeditor/wiki/Home

I wrote the given piece of code in my application's "model/db1.y" and "views/default/index.html" as directed in the above links, but things are not working correct. I am a newbie in web2py. Please help me installing an editor (preferably which supports programming languages) in detailed steps. Thanks!

Comment: Installing editors different than ck-editor4 will also suffice my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:
in db.py:

```
from plugin_ckeditor import CKEditor
ckeditor = CKEditor(db)
db.define_table('wpage',
    Field('title'),
    Field('body', 'text',widget=ckeditor.widget),
    auth.signature, # created_on, created_by, modified_on, modified_by, is_active
    format='%(title)s')
```

In default.py:
@

```
auth.requires_login()
def create():
     """creates a new empty wiki page"""
     ckeditor.define_tables()
     form = SQLFORM(db.wpage).process(next=URL('index'))
     return dict(form=form)
```

I used ckeditor.define_tables() in edit() and show() too. Now in show.html, display the formatting using:

```
{{=XML(page.body,sanitize=False)}}
```

This is all explained in the links in your post and 
https://github.com/timrichardson/web2py_ckeditor4

Comment: Man! you solved my problem..... Thanks a lot. :-) . I have one small query though, if you set sanitize=True, then you need to put some permissible attributes there, like b, u, i,.... However, I don't find all the attributes related to complete formatting options provided by an editor. Do you know any method to fix this....?

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I found a simple way to install an editor for web2py app. This is not ck-editor4 plugin but NicEdit. Just two lines of javascript code will do the job.  Following link came as rescue to me.

http://nicedit.com/

Just follow the simple steps in "Quick Start Guide" right hand side. Create a textarea and your work is done.